# Why can I not get the message block in Magento to show on the category page?

Tags: magento

I'm trying to get Magento to redirect after a customer clicks the 'Add to Cart' button over to the category page, which I have done with no problem (after a little bit of searching around, of course) by using a hidden field with the name of "return_url".  This part works perfectly, and the item is added to the cart, and the user is redirected back to the category page.  Once here, no matter what I've tried I cannot get the message block to show the success (or error) message.  Here is my most recent code attempt (in view.phtml):

```
$messages=Mage::getSingleton("checkout/session")->getMessages();
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("core/messages")->setMessages($messages)->getGroupedHtml();
```

Thanks!

Comment: This works with customer/session

Comment: Have you found a solution? I have the same problem. I put messages in customer/session and they do not show in the category page. They just accumulate, and are printed when I access a different page, say the customer account page.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried more simple `addSuccess`/`addError`/`addNotice` functions?

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError(Mage::helper('core')->__('An error'));
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('core')->__('A success'));
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addNotice(Mage::helper('core')->__('A notice'));
```

Comment: Yes and No.  I can retrieve those in the view.phtml file if I set hem there.  However, I'm trying to retrieve the ones that are set in the CartController file that normally show up when you don't redirect the url.

Comment: Hmmmm, without testing personally, I would imagine those messages are dropped upon the redirect - but I could be wrong.

Comment: Actually....just used print_r on it, and I'm getting the message object.  It seems the problem is with displaying the block.

Comment: Incidentally, where are you trying to create that block, in your controller, block class or phtml file itself?

Comment: in the view phtml file itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a message to different session model types like "catalog", "customer", "checkout" or simple "core".

Same as:

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')
```

In your case, the customer session messages are not initialized in the category controller. Take a look at

```
\Mage_Catalog_CategoryController::viewAction
```

The end of the function should look like this:

```
$this->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session');
$this->_initLayoutMessages('checkout/session');
$this->renderLayout();
```

To display the messages from "customer/session", this area must look like this:

```
$this->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session');
$this->_initLayoutMessages('customer/session');
$this->_initLayoutMessages('checkout/session');
$this->renderLayout();
```